# updating a list of records with linq-to-sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a table that has 2 columns: FruitID, FruitSize. I want to write a query that takes in a list of FruitIDs and a FruitSize and that sets the new FruitSize for all the fruits.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void ChangeFruitSizes(List<long> TheFruitIDs, long NewFruitSize)
{
   using (SomeDC MyDC = new SomeDC())
   {
      var TheFruits = (from f in MyDC.Fruits
                       where TheFruitIDs.Contains(f.FruitID)
                       select f).ToList();

      foreach (Fruits f in TheFruits)
      {
          f.FruitSize = NewFruitSize;
      }

      MyDC.SubmitChanges();

   }
}
```

It's currently not bugging but the fields in the database aren't updated. Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: didn't you mean `where TheFruitIDs.Contains(f.FruitID)`?

Comment: For feedback on your code, [codereview.SE] is usually the better place to go.

Comment: @codesparkle: yes, typo, fixed.

Comment: Is this a code-review or is the code not working for you? You say the fields are not updated but the answers are code-reviews. I'm confused.

Comment: @usr: no, it's not code review; unfortunately the code is not working at all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To write this in more concise way, you can try [ForEach()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx) in list like below:

```
using (SomeDC MyDC = new SomeDC())
{
    (from f in MyDC.Fruits
               where TheFruitIDs.Contains(f.FruitID)
               select f).ToList().ForEach(F => F.FruitSize = NewFruitSize);

    MyDC.SubmitChanges();

}
```

Comment: thanks, this looks more concise; anything that could go wrong here?

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work: TheFruits is underlined and saying "Cannot assign void to an implicitly typed local variable".

Comment: Ohh yes @frenchie The ForEach is a void method it doesn't return anything. I have updated my answer have a look again.

Comment: @frenchie, have you fixed this?

Comment: Yes, I fixed that but it still doesn't update the records in the DB.

Comment: @frenchie, i guess somehow the primary key is removed or not added initially in fruits table. Check it out.

Comment: ? The table doesn't have a primary key. Do you think that could be the issue??

Comment: Yes @frenchie if you are using DBML or EDMX. You must need to specify primary key.

Comment: okay @frenchie than you must need to specify primary key and you problem will definitely solved.

Comment: ok, thanks. I need to see how I can modify the DB model then.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at the code everything is correct. Probably the error is at what is not shown: The model. I suspect you don't have a primary key defined. Define a primary key on the ID field and re-create the model (remove the table from the designer and add it back).

Comment: Yes, the table doesn't have a primary key: it's a join table where FruitID can appear multiple times.